# How to handle Content-Range for pagination on Restangular?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The API i am using returns header "Content-range" for lists :

```
Request : GET /users
Response contains : Content-Range: 0-49/1337
```

What is the correct way to generalize the retrieval (and parsing) of this header value with Restangular ?

Do i have to make my own function ?

Is there a existing method that can "catch" every response, check if the header is there and then append the parsed values (i.e : limit, range, total_count, page number) to Restangular returned object ?

Answer (score 1):

Restangular has [addresponseinterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor) for catching responses. You can catch your response there and get `response.headers`.

**You should return a restangularized element in the interceptor** otherwise you cannot get any data in your controllers or services...

So an example can be like this...

```
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {

        var data = response.data;
        var contentRange = response.headers("Content-Range");

        if (contentRange) {
            data.limit = contentRange.limit;
        }

        return data;
    });
```

As you see you can add Restangular response interceptor on any angular config blog by injection `RestangularProvider`

Comment: I tried your solution but can't get my "Content-Range" inside response.headers.

Comment: @MartinH-Works I made edit for you to use. Headers is a function so you should call it with the name of the header parameter you want. In your case it is 'Conten-Range'...

Comment: Ok i had to modify my API to add : "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" -> "Content-Range" or the header is not accessible (although present in the response). Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

After a few iterations on @wickY26 solution here is a technique that worked well for me :

### Prerequisite

As mentioned in the question the API response contains this header :

```
Content-Range: 0-9/150
```

Which mean : The returned list will start at the 1st element (starting at 0) until the 9th on a total of 150.

On the other side the request has to include a "range=x-y" :

```
https://api.myapp.com/contents/?range=10-20
```

Code below will only work inside those contraints.

### First step

Make Restangular grab all incoming responses from API. If we have a "Content-Range" header then append a pagination object with all important informations regarding pagination (from, to, total, numPage, currentPage) :

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .config(dataConfigResponse);

dataConfigResponse.$inject = ['RestangularProvider'];
function dataConfigResponse(RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {

        var responseData = response.data;
        var contentRange = response.headers('Content-Range');

        if (contentRange) {
            var rangeFields = contentRange.split(/\s|-|\//);

            var paginationFrom = parseInt(rangeFields[0]) + 1;
            var paginationTo = parseInt(rangeFields[1]) + 1;
            var paginationTotal = parseInt(rangeFields[2]);
            var paginationSubTotal = parseInt(paginationTo - paginationFrom);

            responseData.pagination = {
                from: paginationFrom,
                to: paginationTo,
                total: paginationTotal,
                numPages: Math.ceil(paginationTotal / paginationSubTotal),
                currentPage: Math.ceil(paginationFrom / paginationSubTotal)
            };
        }

        return responseData;
    });
}
```

### Second step

Make Restangular intercept all outgoing requests to the API. When the action is a getList we append "?range=10-20" to the next query

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .config(dataConfigRequest);

dataConfigRequest.$inject = ['RestangularProvider'];
function dataConfigRequest(RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
        if (operation === 'getList') {
            if (Object.keys(params).length) {
                params.range = ((params._page - 1) * params._perPage) + '-' + (params._page * params._perPage - 1);

                delete params._page;
                delete params._perPage;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### Third step

Now the controller which is displaying the list.

```
function dashboardContentListCtrl($scope, dataService) {

    // Pagination starting values
    $scope.maxSize = 6;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.limit = 20;

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        $scope.params = {_page: $scope.currentPage, _perPage: $scope.limit};

        dataService.getAllContents($scope.params).then(function (contents) {
            $scope.pagination = contents.pagination;

            $scope.contents = contents.plain();

        }).catch(function () {

            $scope.contents = [];
        });
    };

    $scope.pageChanged();
```

On my app the pagination view component is angular-ui pagination directive, looking like this :

```
<pagination class="pagination-sm" 
boundary-links="true" 
ng-hide="pagination.total < limit" 
total-items="pagination.total" 
items-per-page="limit" 
ng-model="currentPage" 
max-size="maxSize" 
rotate="false" 
ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```